# Router Configuration CakePHP Remove Pages in URL

Tags: php, cakephp, router, cakephp-2.1, clean-urls

I'm currently looking for a solution to remove "Pages" from the URL but not make it hard to add a controller.

I looked around and searched on Google for a solution, but the best solution they could give was this:

```
Router::Connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

[Example Link](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/joelstein/2007/05/02/taking-advantage-of-the-pages-controller)

But the problem with this solution is that every time I want to add a controller I need to add the following lines toe my *config/routers.php* file

```
Router::Connect('/Users/:action/, array('controller' => 'Users');
Router::Connect('/users/:action/, array('controller' => 'Users');
```

The reason why I added these two lines is because I didn't want the URL to be case sensitive.

I also know that it doesn't happen that often, once the website is "FINISHED", that the controllers are being changed.

So my solution was the following:

```
/*
 * Get URL
 * Seperate in array
 * Remove empty elements
 */
$url = array_filter(explode("/", Router::url()));

/*
 * Get Controllers list
 */
$Controllers = App::objects('controller');
$CleanControllers = array();

/*
 * Remove string 'Controller' from element
 * lower string
 */
foreach($Controllers as $Controller) {
    $CleanControllers[] = strtolower(str_replace('Controller', '', $Controller));
}

/*
 * Check if first element, from URL, is NOT a controllers array
 */
if(!in_array(strtolower(reset($url)), $CleanControllers)) {
    /*
     * Forward to "Pages" controller 
     */
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
    Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display'));
}

/*
 * Check if first element, from URL, is NOT a controllers array
 */

CakePlugin::routes();

require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

So my question is this solution a performance KILLER? If so, does anyone know a better solution?

Because when I looking at the advanced routing from CakePHP, it seems to me that I need a SUPER Advanced routing... Or I simply don't understand it.

CAKEPHP Version 2.1

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is basically correct, there is no magic switch which will fix this issue. I wrote an [article about this kind of routing](http://lecterror.com/articles/view/advanced-routing-with-cakephp-one-example) a while ago, it's for earlier cake versions but still relevant with minor changes (I hope).